# Angular: force validate template driven form

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form like this:

```
<form #docForm="ngForm">
...
<input type="text"
       required
       [attr.name]="name"
       [(ngModel)]="value" />
</form>
```

Then I have a button that should check if form is valid even if all form's fields are untouched. When button is clicked all invalid form's fields should be validated and highlited. So my component's code looks like this:

```
@ViewChild(NgForm, {static: false}) form: NgForm;
...
someButtonHandler() {

     // this.form.controls collection is always empty! 

     for (const fieldName in this.form.controls) { 
         ... do something with form controls 
     }
  }
```

Am I on the right way? Why do *this.form.controls* collection is always empty?

May be there are some more correct approaches to solve my problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not sure why you're going with a template driven form, wouldn't a reactive one be better? (I am not too familiar with template ones so I am honestly curious about your reasoning :) )

Also I think this is a bit difficult to debug as it is, could you by any chance make a new angular project containing your code in https://stackblitz.com/ and share it? If you do I would love to play around and see if I can figure something out :)

Comment: It's **name** not attr.name:`<input type="text" required [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="value" />`. BTW Do you not saw an error in console when use attr.name?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your form in `someButtonHandler`, you can pass it when calling the function, in your html: `someButtonHandler(docForm)`.

Alternatively, you can also access it if you link it in the component using viewchild:

```
@ViewChild('docForm') courseForm: NgForm;

someButtonHandler() {

     for (const fieldName in this.courseForm.form.controls) { 
         ... do something with form controls 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use model class with template driven form this will validate form on button click.

For example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class User {
  public name: string;
  public email: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  model = new User();

  constructor() { }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Template-driven Form</h4>

  <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">

    <div *ngIf="model.isName" class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': userForm.submitted && name.invalid }" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="userForm.submitted && name.invalid">
        <p *ngIf="name.errors.required">Name is required</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': userForm.submitted && email.invalid }" email required>
      <div *ngIf="userForm.submitted && email.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
        <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">Must be a valid email address</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{userForm.valid}}
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this type of validations its better to use reactive forms as it provide more flexibility on form control actions. we can do this validations in template driven forms but it will be more work load, you can try like this in template driven forms.
form will be

```html
<form #contactForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm)">

  <p>
    <label for="firstname">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required minlength="10" #firstname="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="contact.firstname">
  </p>
  <div *ngIf="!firstname?.valid && (firstname?.dirty || firstname?.touched)" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="firstname.errors.required">
      First Name is required
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="firstname.errors.minlength">
      First Name Minimum Length is {{firstname.errors.minlength?.requiredLength}}
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <p>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required maxlength="15" #lastname="ngModel" 
            pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"  [(ngModel)]="contact.lastname">
  </p>
  <div *ngIf="!lastname?.valid && (lastname?.dirty || lastname?.touched)" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="lastname.errors.required">
      Last Name is required
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="lastname.errors.maxlength">
      Last Name Minimum Length is {{lastname.errors.maxlength?.requiredLength}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="lastname.errors.pattern">
      Only characters are allowed
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">Submit</button>
  </p>
 
  <p>{{contactForm.valid}} </p>
 
</form>
```

and ts code will be

```
onSubmit(contact_form:any) {
  // getting all your form controls
  let form_controls=contact_form.form.controls
  try {
    for (let control_name in form_controls) {
      form_controls[control_name].touched = true;
      // you can update other form control validations here
    }
  } catch { }
}
```